# website speed performance as it relates to database load

Tags: sql

I am new to this but I am curious, does the size of a database negatively affect page load speeds. Like if you had to fetch 20 items from a small database with 20,000 records and then fetch those same 20 items from a database of  2,000,000 records would it be safe to assume that the latter would be much slower all else being equal? And would buying more dedicated servers improve the speed. I want to educate myself on this so I can be prepared for future events.

Comment: I would start first by educating myself on indexing

Comment: It _might_ be slower, but if it is it will be by an amount that you won't notice. The point of a database is to select data quickly and easily... If you don't know how to decide how to scale your infrastructure to the appropriate level it's worth employing someone who does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe to assume that the bigger data is *much* slower.  An intelligently designed database is going to do such page accesses through an index.  For most real problems, the index will fit in memory.  The cost of any page access is then:

- Cost of looking up where the appropriate records are in the database.
- Cost of loading the database pages containing those records into memory.

The cost of index lookups varies little (relatively) based on the size of the index.  So, the typical worst case scenario is about 20 disk accesses for getting the data.  And, for a wide range of overall table sizes, this doesn't change.

If the table is small and fits in memory, then you have the advantage of fully caching it in the in-memory page cache.  This will speed up queries in that case.  But the upper limit on performance is fixed.

If the index doesn't fit in memory, then the situation is a bit more complicated.

What would typically increase performance for a single request is having more memory.  You need more processors if you have many multiple requests at the same time.

And, if you are seeing linear performance degradation, then you have a database poorly optimized for your application needs.  Fixing the database structure in that case will generally be better than throwing more hardware at the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for that response, it answered my question completely.